# Delete rows that are repeated for only some of the columns of the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Considering the sample dataframe as:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(rep(1,4),4,7,8), b=c(rep(4,4),6,8,3), 
                 c=c(rep("hey",4),"hi","hello","salam"), 
                 d=c("q","r","g","y","d","e","y"), e=c(2,6,43,56,6,23,4))
```

I want to remove the rows that are the same for columns `a`, `b`, `c`. The desired output would be three rows as

```
    a b     c     d   e
1   1 4    hey    q   2 
5   4 6    hi     d   6
6   7 8   hello   e   23
7   8 3   salam   y   4
```

Comment: You can also do `df %>% group_by(a, b, c) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the first row

```
df[!duplicated(df[,c("a","b","c")]),]

  a b     c d  e
1 1 4   hey q  2
5 4 6    hi d  6
6 7 8 hello e 23
7 8 3 salam y  4
```

Comment: Yes you are right! I will update!

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` solution is:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(a, b, c, .keep_all = TRUE)
```